# To fetch bigger dataset from twitter

Tags: uses-of-open-data, social-media, python

I need twitter data for my project, but with streaming api I am able to get only 15 min window frame.Hence a very smaller sample space.
I have a written code in python as follows

```
import tweep
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

consumer_key = "T---------------------------------------f"
consumer_secret = "N-------------------------------------------d"
access_key = "3-------------------------------------------------------u"
access_secret = "M-----------------------------------------X"

# authorize
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# get streaming tweets by hashtag
hashtag = '#madebygoogle'
class MyListener(StreamListener):
     def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            print data
            return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print('Error on_data: %s' % str(e))
        return True
    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True

twitter_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener())
twitter_stream.filter(track=[hashtag])
```

How can I increase the rate of tweets??